# cl: compile time vs. run time: inf vs. -nan(ind)

Tags: c, floating-point, nan, ieee-754, cl

Sample code (`t50.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <assert.h>

const float d1 = NAN;
const float d2 = -0x0p+0;
const float d3 = NAN / -0x0p+0;

typedef union { uint32_t u; float d; } u_t;

int main(void)
{
        u_t u1;
        u_t u2;
        u_t u3;

        u1.d = *(volatile float*)&d1 / *(volatile float*)&d2;
        u2.d = d3;
        u3.d = d1 / d2;
        if ( u1.u != u2.u || u1.u != u3.u )
        {
                printf("error:\n");
                printf("u1 (run time)     %08"PRIx32" %.*e\n", u1.u, DECIMAL_DIG, u1.d);
                printf("u2 (compile time) %08"PRIx32" %.*e\n", u2.u, DECIMAL_DIG, u2.d);
                printf("u3                %08"PRIx32" %.*e\n", u3.u, DECIMAL_DIG, u3.d);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Compiler invocation: `cl t50.c /O1 /fp:precise && t50`

Expected result: `<nothing>`

Actual result (same for `cl x86` and `cl x64`):

```
error:
u1 (run time)     ffc00000 -nan(ind)
u2 (compile time) 7f800000 inf
u3                ffc00000 -nan(ind)
```

I've specified `/fp:strict`: `cl t50.c /O1 /fp:strict && t50`, but got:

```
t50.c(8): error C2099: initializer is not a constant
t50.c(10): error C2099: initializer is not a constant
```

`cl` version: `19.25.28611 for x86` and `19.25.28611 for x64`.

Compare with `gcc` (10.2.0) and `clang` (11.0.0):

```
gcc t50.c -O2 && a.exe
<nothing>

clang t50.c -O2 && a.exe
<nothing>
```

Why? What I'm missing here?
What the standard (C / IEEE) says?

UPD1:

1. Same result for `if ( u1.d != u2.d || u1.d != u3.d )`.
2. Same result `w/o unions` (i.e. using `float u1, u2, u3`).

UPD2:

1. compiler's NAN definition: `Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h`: `#define NAN ((float)(INFINITY * 0.0F))`.
2. Output for `u1.d = NAN; printf("NAN  %08"PRIx32" %.*e\n", u1.u, DECIMAL_DIG, u1.d);` (for both `cl x86` and `cl x64`): `NAN  ffc00000 -nan(ind)`.

Comment: Regarding the "initializer not constant" errors, it's possible that MSVC defines the `NAN` macro as a function call.

Comment: You're missing a decent standard conforming compiler... sadly.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Standards don't promise anything about what you get when type-punning with a union, do they?

Comment: @NateEldredge as per the C standard, type-punning through unions is totally ok. It's implementation defined, yes, but it should work. What is wrong here is probably some bogus floating point math quirks of `cl`.

Comment: "[C2099](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2099?view=msvc-160) can also occur because the compiler is not able to perform constant folding on an expression under /fp:strict because the floating point precision environment settings (see _controlfp_s for more information) may differ from compile to run time."

Comment: `NAN` is a macro that eventually expands to `((float)(((float)(1e+300 * 1e+300)) * 0.0F))` (where the multiplication overflows to infinity).

Comment: MSVC is a C++ compiler. It doesn't support modern C standards well so don't use it for C

Comment: `NAN` is not required to exist if implementation lacks quiet NaN support. pmor, post compiler's `NAN` definition, if able and `u1.d = NAN; printf("NAN  %08"PRIx32" %.*e\n", u1.u, DECIMAL_DIG, u1.d);`

Comment: "u2 (compile time) 7f800000 inf" is a potential output if compiler supports NAN as C does not require NAN behavior per IEEE.  Use a [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64617357/cl-compile-time-vs-run-time-inf-vs-nanind#comment114254820_64617357) compiler.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica See UPD2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

`cl` does not follow [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) concerning `NAN`.

> What I'm missing here?

Assuming a compliant C compiler follows IEEE.

> What the standard C says?

C is lax with specs in the `NAN` department.  I'd rate the compiler as compliant, just a weak quality of implementation concerning `NAN`.

> What the standard IEEE says?

Non-compliant.