# Why QNAN == QNAN does not lead to raising FE_INVALID exception?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, floating-point-exceptions, c17

Code (t125.c):

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#if _MSC_VER
#pragma fenv_access (on)
#else
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
#endif

void show_fe_exceptions(void)
{
    printf("exceptions raised: ");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO))     printf(" FE_DIVBYZERO");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT))       printf(" FE_INEXACT");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_INVALID))       printf(" FE_INVALID");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_OVERFLOW))      printf(" FE_OVERFLOW");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW))     printf(" FE_UNDERFLOW");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT)==0) printf(" none");
    printf("\n");
}

typedef union { uint32_t u; float f; } ufloat;

int main(void)
{
    _Bool b;
    ufloat uqnan;
    volatile float f;

    uqnan.u = 0x7fc00000;
    f = uqnan.f;

    b = f == f;
    show_fe_exceptions();
    return b ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Invocations:

```
$ gcc t125.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c17 && ./a.exe
t125.c:7: warning: ignoring ‘#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS’ [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    7 | #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
      |
exceptions raised:  none

$ clang t125.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c17 && ./a.exe
t125.c:7:14: warning: pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON is not supported, ignoring pragma [-Wunknown-pragmas]
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
             ^
1 warning generated.
exceptions raised:  none

$ cl t125.c /fp:strict /std:c17 && t125
exceptions raised:  none
```

Question: why `QNAN == QNAN` does not lead to raising `FE_INVALID` exception?

UPD. Reason of the question: (false, see below) assumption that `<any_NAN> == <any_NAN>` leads to raising `FE_INVALID` exception.

UPD2. Changed code: from `f = *(float*)&qnan` to `f = uqnan.f` (type punning via union). This is to avoid violation of the aliasing rules of the C standard.

Comment: Can you say why you think this operation _should_ lead to the invalid flag being set? Admittedly, the relevant standards aren't _completely_ unambiguous here: assuming `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined, annex F of the C standard just says "The relational and equality operators provide IEC 60559 comparisons", while IEC 60559 describes both "compareQuietEqual" and "compareSignalingEqual". IEC 60559 does however also say: "Language standards _should_ map their notations for the symbols = and ≠ to the Quiet predicates [...]".

Comment: Because the Q in QNaN stands for Quiet.

Comment: Do not write `*(float*)&`, because it violates the aliasing rules in the C standard. Use `float f; memcpy(&f, &qnan, sizeof f);` or `float f = (union { unsigned u; float f; }) {0x7fc00000} .f;`.

Comment: What does your code give for `f <= f` in place of `f == f`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Correct, thanks. @Mark Dickinson Thanks for the idea. For `f <= f` the things become hot: `gcc: FE_INVALID, clang: none, cl (msvc): FE_INVALID`. Any explanations?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Though none of them define `__STDC_IEC_559__` with definition of 1. However, they are (seems) not _required_ to define `__STDC_IEC_559__` with definition of 1. See updated answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I thought the union trick was potentially undefined behavior these days too, and you had to use `memcpy` to be sure.

Comment: @MarkRansom Quote from comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64617357/1778275): _as per the C standard, type-punning through unions is totally ok. It's implementation defined, yes, but it should work_.

Comment: @MarkRansom: It is defined in C but not in C++.

Comment: @EricPostpischil _Because the Q in QNaN stands for Quiet_: C standard explicitly talks about _arithmetic operations_, IEEE 754 explicitly talks about _unordered-quiet predicates in Table 5.3_. What about C standard library functions? Can we conclude / assume that `lrintf(NAN)` (for example) shall not lead to raising `FE_INVALID`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Or is the behavior wrt raising `FE_INVALID` _unspecified_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (E) (emphasis added):

> 5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating types <float.h>
>
> 3    A quiet NaN propagates through almost every arithmetic operation *without raising a floating-point exception*; a signaling NaN generally raises a floating-point exception when occurring as an arithmetic operand.

See also: [What is the difference between quiet NaN and signaling NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118408/what-is-the-difference-between-quiet-nan-and-signaling-nan).

UPD. Yes, it seems that *equality does not count as an arithmetic operation for this purpose*. Then here is a quote from IEEE 754-2008 (emphasis added):

> 5.11 Details of comparison predicates
> Programs that explicitly take account of the possibility of quiet NaN operands may use the unordered-quiet predicates in Table 5.3 which *do not signal such an invalid operation exception*.

For example, the predicate `LT EQ` shall not lead to raising invalid operation exception. However, we see (in the comments above) that for `f <= f` both `gcc` and `cl (msvc)` raise `FE_INVALID`. Is it a bug / defect? Though none of them define `__STDC_IEC_559__` with definition of 1. However, they are not *required*:

> `__STDC_IEC_559__` The integer constant 1, *intended* to indicate conformance to the specifications in annex F (IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic).

Comment: I'm not sure that equality counts as an arithmetic operation for this purpose. I'd also suspect that an order comparison operator involving a quiet NaN (e.g., `qnan <= qnan`) *should* signal the invalid operation exception, in which case the contents of 5.2.4.2.2 aren't quite enough here.