# MSVC: run time vs. compile time: 1.000000 vs. -nan(ind)

Tags: c, visual-c++, floating-point, nan, standards-compliance

Sample code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef double T;

T min(T a, T b)
{
        return a < b ? a : b;
}

#define MIN(a,b)        ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define ONE             ((T)1)

int main(void)
{
        printf("%f %f\n", min(NAN,ONE), MIN(NAN,ONE));
}
```

Invocation:

```
$ cl t35a.c /std:c11 && ./t35a.exe
1.000000 -nan(ind)
```

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior?view=msvc-170):

> `/fp:precise`
>
> By default, the compiler uses `/fp:precise` behavior.
>
> Expressions that involve special values (NaN, +infinity, -infinity, -0.0) are processed  according to IEEE-754 specifications.

IEEE 754-2008, 5.11 Details of comparison predicates:

> Every NaN shall compare unordered with everything, including itself.

So, if every NaN shall compare unordered with everything, including itself, then `a < b ? a : b` shall produce `b` if `a` or `b` or both is/are NaN. If `b` is one, then why MSVC produces `-nan(ind)` instead of `1.000000`? Is it a bug?

Comment: [Related/Dupe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64617357/10871073)

Comment: Note that changing the compile option to `/fp:strict` resolves the issue.

Comment: @AdrianMole MSVC team fixed "inf instead of -nan(ind)". This one seems unfixed. The `/fp:strict` very possibly leads to evaluation of `((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))` at run time. However, `/fp:precise` promises that `NaN` is supported.

Comment: But the current (latest) MSVC has `#define NAN (-(float)(INFINITY * 0.0F))`. Whether or not this is a "bug" or a case of "non-compliance" is: (a) opinion-based; (b) much the same as your previous question (I can't really post an answer that adds anything to that earlier one). But I'm not voting to close ... because I'm not *sure* (and, if were to VTC as a dupe, it would be a unilateral vote, because the System thinks I'm a C expert).

Comment: ... also, my latest VS-2022 gives just `nan`, rather than what you have indicated.

Comment: Re "`#define NAN (-(float)(INFINITY * 0.0F))`": MS confirmed that it is an issue: "Thanks for reporting this and help us improve our libraries. This issue has been fixed and will be available in a future update."